# Excel VBA Continuous function/sub execution

Tags: excel, vba

How to continuously execute a Function/Sub or every time the mouse (or mouse wheel) moves?

`SelectionChange` or `Change` will not work for this as intended.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Const FreezeRow As Long = 23
            Dim WindowTopRow As Range
            Dim wnd As Window
            Dim WindowRange As Range
            Dim MessageB As String
            
            Set wnd = ActiveWindow
            Set WindowRange = wnd.VisibleRange
            Set WindowTopRow = WindowRange.Rows(1)
            
            
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If WindowTopRow.Row > FreezeRow + 1 Then
'            MessageB = MsgBox(WindowTopRow.Row, vbInformation, "Switch on Freeze")
                    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = FreezeRow
                    Cells(FreezeRow + 1, 1).Activate
                    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
           End If
           If WindowTopRow.Row <= FreezeRow + 1 Then
'           MessageB = MsgBox(WindowTopRow.Row, vbInformation, "Switch off Freeze")
                    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
            End If

             Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I want to freeze specific row once that row-1 is on the top of the screen and unfreeze it once that row is on the top of the screen.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve over and above the built-in freeze rows functionality of excel - can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that. There is no easy way at least

Answer (score 0):

Your code functions well as you've explained. Since you're using the SelectionChange event, the code will trigger whenever you click on any cell in the sheet.

[image: on Freeze]

[image: off Freeze]

Comment: How to change that to scrolling?